# 404 error in jpeg format images on laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, image, webserver, jpeg

I have a system in Laravel hosted on hostinger, apparently out of nowhere the jpeg images return error 404, if I switch to png or another format it works normally, if I try to pull the link it returns page not Found, if I change it to png or another format I can access the image, does anyone know what it can be?

Comment: have you checked the permission of jpeg files?

Comment: yes, everyone has permission

Comment: try bs `ls` command to list if that image exists in server. just to make sure

Comment: yes, it exists I can download it as jpeg and open normally, if I change the format to jpg, png I can access the photo through the link, without changing anything

Comment: can you post the link here

Comment: follows link, I made a copy of the image and changed the format for you to see.
https://coremobilidade.com.br/public/storage/provider/profile/1QmuzpjhNsWQ5qodBrXdFOytMJYSyFvuPBaAe1F8.png

https://coremobilidade.com.br/public/storage/provider/profile/1QmuzpjhNsWQ5qodBrXdFOytMJYSyFvuPBaAe1F8.jpeg

Comment: If image is of `PNG` format it will never work if you change it's link to `JPEG` format.
Actually when you hit url 'https://coremobilidade.com.br/public/storage/provider/profile/1QmuzpjhNsWQ5qodBrXdFOytMJYSyFvuPBaAe1F8.png' that image exists in directory it be show the original image, but if you hit this url `https://coremobilidade.com.br/public/storage/provider/profile/1QmuzpjhNsWQ5qodBrXdFOytMJYSyFvuPBaAe1F8.jpg` then that image with jpg format doesn't exist on server it would definitely give 404 error.

Comment: So it's the opposite, it's in jpeg, but when I change it to png it works, but the original format is jpeg

Comment: use this command `file MyPNG.png` in cli to check the original format of that image

Comment: So I managed to fix the problem , i changed my htacces in folder public

    RewriteRule !.(js|gif||jpeg|jpg|png|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|map)$ index.php

was without jpeg so other formats worked, thank you very much for the help